# How to detect a longpress in delphi (managing right clicks on touch devices)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl, long-press

users of my win32 application when running on a touch device such as a Win8 Tablet experience he problem of LackofRightClick.

is there a way to make te popupmenu appear when using a single finger?

Somehow "Longpress = RightClick.OnClick"... (by somehow telling windows that I want to use longpress as RightClick, so when user lonpresses with finger the system shows the popupmenu)

Is it possible? Which are other solutions anyone foudn for a similar context?

Comment: yes, anyway by searching i also found that Press+Tab is as rightclicking: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/using-touch-gestures

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/9629063/960757...

Comment: This should work. Windows should translate long press into the appropriate right-click messages. Perhaps your control is non-standard?